# Php Export to excel and show into screen simultaneously?

Tags: php

I have this code to export the results of a mysql select and it works very well. But, I need to show a little information on the screen after file is downloaded. I will appreciate any help!!!

```
if ($results){
    function outputCSV($results) {
        $titulo = array('SMS_ID','ORIGEN','DESTINO','FECHA_ENTREGA','RESULTADO','CODIGO_ENTREGA','MENSAJE','TIPO_SMS');
        $outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');
        $first = true;
        fputcsv($outputBuffer, $titulo);
        foreach($results as $val) {
            fputcsv($outputBuffer, $val);
        }
        fclose($outputBuffer);
    }
    $filename = 'ConsultaMSISDN-TSE';
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.csv");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    outputCSV($results);
    $conn->close();
    exit;
} else {
    print "<p align=\"CENTER\"><h1>Consulta no arrojó resultados.!</h1></p>";
    echo "<br><a href='panel-consultas_4-TSE-MSISDN.php'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: You can't send two responses to the browser - your script has to either result in a download or display a webpage. The general workaround is to display a "Your download is starting..." page that then redirects to the download script.

Comment: OK, so I will move my export function to other php page.